# Is it true that $2\max_{|z|=1} | z^n+ (\sum_{ i=2}^{n-1} a_iz^i ) + a_1 z+a_0| \geq \max_{|z|= 1} |a_1z+a_0|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials

I come across to prove or disprove an inequality which is  $$2\max_{|z|=1} | z^n+ (\sum_{ i=2}^{n-1} a_iz^i ) + a_1 z+a_0| \geq \max_{|z|=1} |a_1z+a_0|,$$

where $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $a_i$ are real.

This seems can be solved by brutal force ($z=e^{it}$) but it does not work for me. I also tried some polynomial and it seems to be true.

Any approach that one could suggest for me?

Any help would be appreciated!